# enum method not printing out the expected value

Tags: rust

Could somone point out what I am doing wrong here? Why isn't the call() method printing the value of self, which should be hello?

```
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}
impl Message {
    fn call(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let m = Message::Write(String::from("Hello"));
    m.call();
  
}
```

Comment: Your code with not compile because `Message` does not implement `Debug`. When I fix that and run it, it prints `Write("Hello")`. What exactly do you expect to be output, and what do you get?

Comment: @PitaJ Can you put that as an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Message` type must implement the `Debug` trait which brings `{:?}` and `{:#?}` formatting support. It can be done with the help of the `derive` attribute macro.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Message {
    ...
}

// the other way is a manual implementation
impl Debug for Message {
    ...
}
```